# Locate file in folder further down the hierarchy

Tags: powershell

I need to locate a .exe file and run it, only knowing the directory which is a few levels higher than the .exe file

EG If I have this folder structure:

test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\win7-x64\program.exe

and I only know the test folder, I need to get the path to program.exe, without knowing the name of the .exe file either (but there is only one .exe file).

So something like:

```
gcm *.exe test
```

Where test is the source folder to look in.

How do I do this?

Comment: What if there are multiple exe's? Do you want to take the first found or fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like what you're looking for:

```
$path = 'test'
$program = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.exe -Recurse
& $program.FullName
```

The `&` operator there is the call operator; it can run an executable given the full path to it.

Answer (score 1):

`gcm` is an [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847830.aspx) for [`Get-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849711.aspx). You're looking for `gci` ([`Get-ChildItem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)). Use the parameter `-Recurse` to recurse into subfolders and `-Filter` to filter for files with a particular extension:

```
Get-ChildItem test -Filter *.exe -Recurse
```

Note that, as [@Guvante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155996/locate-file-in-folder-further-down-the-hierarchy#comment65655584_39155996) pointed out, this might return more than one executable (or even none at all), so you need to decide how you want to handle all these cases (run all executables, the first, the last, none, fail with an error, fail silently, ...).

Once you have a matching file you can run it for instance via the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx):

```
$exe = Get-ChildItem ... | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand FullName
& $exe
```